# How to get back Visual Studio's old way of alerting of suggestions by darkening code instead of by 3 dots?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio used to alert us of unused variables by darkening them. Now (version 16.10.2) it fills the code with three dots everywhere, which look a little like code and are more confusing.

Is there a way to get the old way back?

Comment: Looks like when you just declare variable it creates a dotted grey box around it. But if you used it once this box goes away. Then you only have 4 dots. But how does it look like code?

Comment: In many cases the dots look like I've typed a dot there, or perhaps a comma, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 16.10.3 now

It looks like they changed it back.

So if you still have it - update VS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a color control for the ellipses called "Suggestion Ellipses...".  You could set the foreground color of it to the same color as your editors background to get a sense that its turned off.  You'll still see it when you select the item though like so:

[image]